# Facebook Analytics shows two different event source groups

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-analytics

Facebook Analytics is showing two different event source groups. One for my page activity and one for the pixel activity. How can I merge them?

Answer (score 1):

Since event source group are entities that combine event sources (Page, Pixel, etc), one cannot combine event source groups. Instead, you can create a new event source group that contains the event sources in the event source groups that you want to combine.

Event Source Groups can be created from [Facebook Analytics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/omni-channel-analytics#creating_an_esg) or [Business Manager](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/975136875941680) and can be used to combine Apps, Pixels, Pages and Offline Event Sets. You can view analytics on these event source groups in [Facebook Analytics](http://www.facebook.com/analytics).